# Populating large set of parameters with Setter methods

Tags: java, rest-assured, jsonschema2pojo

I am using POJO to create and fetch data. These POJOs represent our APIs and we use them for testing through REST Assured.

I have a `RequestDTO` class with 30 variables. Since this is a DTO, I am using 30 setter methods in my class for updating there values.

I am calling these setter methods as below with method chaining. I am using `varList` variable to read data from csv and supply to this DTO.

However this looks clumsy, less readable & incorrect. I want to know what is a good approach/design pattern here. As I have fairly less knowledge around best practices & design pattern.

Sample code:

```
    public static void setRequestDTO(List<Object> varList) {
        MyRequestDTO myrequest = new MyRequestDTO()
            .setkey1(varList.get(0).toString())
            .setkey2(varList.get(1).toString())
            // ........
            .setkey30(varList.get(30).toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I believe your DTO is too bloated - is there *really* no other way that you can perhaps break this down into smaller classes?

Secondly, you're using a `List<Object>` but all of the examples show that you're using String values - is there a chance that you could change the type parameter of the List to eliminate the need for all of the `.toString` calls?

Thirdly, you are depending heavily on your `List` containing all of the necessary elements that you're looking to set on your DTO **and** that they are all in the correct order. This will lead to exceptions being thrown if you have too few elements.

Lastly, while I would consider refactoring this, I'll leave you with one idea that you could proceed with. If you are determined to keep your current DTO structure, then consider putting your `List<Object>` into a constructor for `MyRequestDTO` and then performing all of your setters in there. That way you don't have 30 lines of setters whenever you're instantiating a new instance of this DTO and you're only setting these values on instantiation.